# JPA merge parent with new child

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence

I have the following structure (OneToOne unidirectional)

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    @Column(name = ID)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true )
    @JoinColumn(name = "DRIVER_ID")
    private Driver driver;

    // setters and getters and other properties
}

@Entity
public class Driver {
    @Id
    @Column(name = ID)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // setters and getters and other properties
}
```

The problem is, that if I already have an existing Car, but no driver and I add a driver to the queried Car from the database, the Driver will get inserted (I see the insert query generated).

The following logic happens inside a transaction:

```
// this is a raw version of the code that gets executed, skipped validation and stuff like that
public void addDriver(long carId, Driver driver) {
    entityManager.persist(driver);
    Car car = entityManager.find(Car.class, carId);
    car.setDriver(driver);
}
```

After the transaction is finished, I query the car, but the car doesn't have a driver attached.
Any idea why this is happening and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Is your function marked as @Transactional ? can you show the whole code where you save the object?

Comment: and do you see an UPDATE to the Car object in the database (and in the log)? And where is the "merge" the title mentions?

Comment: I said in the first post that the code is executed inside a transaction :) 
I do see the UPDATE query in the logs.
By merge, I meant to say: update the relation between the parent and child entities. Sorry if the title was misleading.

Comment: Did you actually call merge on your Car?  The code you've shown  only calls persist on the driver, which would have been picked up and persisted anyway through its relationship to the car.  So while this code should cause the relationship change to be picked up, check your actual code to see if you aren't somehow clearing or discarding changes after your find call.  Could it be that maybe something in your code is forcing a flush after the persist, and your EntityManager isn't registered with the transaction so it isn't getting flushed when the transaction commits?

Answer (score 0):

> If you're relying on your entity existing in the database after your
>   call to persist(), but before the transaction commits, then call
>   flush() first.

Refer this for details:

http://blakecaldwell.net/blog/2013/9/3/dont-rely-on-entitymanagerpersist-for-immediate-insert.html

Comment: Not working. If I search for the Car again, in the same transaction, after the driver was persisted, the searched car contains the driver. I don't know if maybe this piece of information helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

And if you try

`public void addDriver(long carId, Driver driver) {

    Car car = entityManager.find(Car.class, carId);
    car.setDriver(driver);
    entityManager.merge(car)
}`

Because you are cascading the car should be inserted and linked.